# MapBox : I want to add option of avoid toll and re route for avoid traffic in navigation

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I can avoid tolls programatically like this

```
  routeOptions.roadClassesToAvoid = .toll
```

also to avoid traffic

```
NavigationRouteOptions(waypoints: [userWaypoint, destinationWaypoint], profileIdentifier: .automobileAvoidingTraffic)
```

but is there any in-build UI in navigatiuoncontroller of MAPBOX where user can avoid or choose path and toll ?
User can have access for this option to select while navigation ?